# Interact with non-restful web pages through python's lxml package

Tags: python, html, interaction

Google has released its Android API in an interactive form, which is friendly to human users.

http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html

Is there any programmatic way to change the API level (select) and get the html contents (response of the selecting) corresponding to the API level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that Google writes all the contents within the page and use css 'id' or 'class' to distinguish program elements of different API levels.

I solve this problem by using html parser, such as beautiful soup or lxml, to look for (select) specific css tags, that work pretty well.